# заменить for i in range на while

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы, while

у меня есть код в котором используется for in range
хочу поменять на while

```
a = int(input('Введите номер билета: '))  
sum_left = 0
sum_right = 0
for i in range(6):
    if i < 3:
        sum_right += a // 10**i % 10
    else:
        sum_left  += a // 10**i % 10 
if sum_left == sum_right:
    print('lucky')
else:
    print('unlucky')
```

С while:

```
a = int(input('Введите номер билета: '))  
sum_left = 0
sum_right = 0
i=1
while i <a:
    if i < 3:
        sum_right += a // 10**i % 10
    else:
        sum_left  += a // 10**i % 10 
if sum_left == sum_right:
    print('счастливый билет')
else:
    print('обычный билет')
```

Comment: А где for собственно?

Comment: Я дал ответ с поправками к первоначальному коду, так что стоит показать и вариант с for, и попытку с while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы забыли изменение i в конце цикла

```
i += 1
```

Кроме того, условие в while неверное. Вероятно, требуется

```
i = 0
```

и

```
while i < 6:
```

Answer (score 0):

Я бы в данном случае обошелся без циклов, а также добавил бы проверку вводимого значения, чтобы не возникла ошибка при преобразовании строки в число:

```
a = input('Введите номер билета: ')
if a.isdigit() and len(a) % 2 == 0:  # проверяем, число ли ввели и равно ли количество цифр в левой и правой половинах 
    digits = list(map(int, list(a)))  # преобразуем строку в список чисел '123321' >> [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1]
    if sum(digits[:len(a) // 2]) == sum(digits[len(a) // 2:]):  # режем список пополам и суммируем числа в срезах
        print('счастливый билет')
    else:
        print('обычный билет')
else:
    print('Вы ввели не номер или число цифр нечетное')
```

```
Введите номер билета: 009333
счастливый билет
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ticket = int(input('Введите номер билета: '))  
sum_left = 0
sum_right = 0
i=0
while i <6:    
    if i < 3:
        sum_right += ticket // 10**i % 10
    else:
        sum_left  += ticket // 10**i % 10 
    i+=1
if sum_left == sum_right:
    print('Счастливый')
else:
    print('Обычный')
```